# Clearing all items in a ContextMenu

Tags: .net, winforms, contextmenu

I am trying to refresh the list of items in my `ContextMenu` control by removing all items and re-adding new ones. I iterate through all items to unhook their `Click` events and dispose them, and then I clear the list, like this:

```
var menuItems = rightClickMenu.MenuItems;
foreach (MenuItem menuItem in menuItems)
{
    menuItem.Click -= menuItem_Click;
    menuItem.Dispose();
}
menuItems.Clear();
```

When I do this, though, a few items are removed, but then I somehow get `null` for `menuItem`, even though I am 100% certain that the collection does not contain any null values. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying the collection in foreach loop, which is not allowed. instead create a copy of collection and dispose it.

```
var menuItems = rightClickMenu.MenuItems.Cast<MenuItem>().ToArray();
foreach (MenuItem menuItem in menuItems)
{
    menuItem.Click -= menuItem_Click;
    menuItem.Dispose();
}
rightClickMenu.MenuItems.Clear();
```

Comment: It works, thanks! After some research, it appears that calling `Dispose` on an item removes it from the menu... Shouldn't that invalidate the enumerator, though?

Comment: @AndrewSun No, Ideally it should throw `InvalidOperationException` may be framework developers forgot. Try the same with `List<T>` you'll get an exception :)